# Find the limit of the sequence $a_{n+1}=(a_{n})^{a_{n}}$

Tags: limits

> Let $a_{0}=\sqrt[3]{3}$, define a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such that: $$a_{n+1}=(a_{n})^{a_{n}}$$
>
> Find the limit of $a_{n}$.

How can I solve this question?

**Edit:** If $a_{0}=3^{1/3}$,and $a_{n+1}=(a_{n})^{1/a_{n}}$,find $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{n}$I conjecture this sequence limit is $1?$

Comment: This is now a very different story (after the edit).

Comment: Your edit *completely* changed the question, invalidating the existing answer. Please, ask a new question, instead of editing the present one.

Comment: Have the curiosity to compute $a_5$, I am not sure that this will support the conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $a_n$ is an increasing sequence, and we will prove this by induction:

1) Since $(\sqrt[3]{3})>1$, so $a_2 =(\sqrt[3]{3})^{\sqrt[3]{3}} > \sqrt[3]{3} =a_1$.

2) If $a_k > a_{k-1}$, then $a_{k+1}=(a_k)^{a_{k}} > (a_k)^{a_{k-1}} > (a_{k-1})^{a_{k-1}} > a_{k}$

Hence, $a_k$ is an increasing sequence. Hence it is either bounded, or unbounded.

Suppose that $a_k$ has a limit point $a$. Then $a>1$ as $a_k>1 \forall k$, but then $a^a=a$ is not possible as $a^a=a \implies a=1$.

Hence no subsequence of $a_k$ converges, hence $a_k$ is unbounded, and has no limit.

---

EDIT : Now our sequence is a different hue altogether.

So $a_1 = \sqrt[3]{3}$. Let us simplify this sequence by taking logarithms on both sides (everything is positive, so we are fine), and then getting $\frac{\ln a_{n+1}}{\ln a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n}$.

Now, I claim $a_i>1$ for all $i$. It's clear that $a_0 > 1$. By induction, if $a_n>1$, then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt[a_n]{a_n} > \sqrt[a_n]{1} > 1$. Hence the claim follows.

Note that $\frac{1}{a_n}<1$ for all $n$. Hence, $\ln a_{n}$ is a decreasing sequence, but does it decrease to zero?

The sequence is certainly bounded below by $1$, and therefore if it is decreasing, it is convergent. However, the limit $a$ must satisfy $a^{\frac{1}{a}} =a$, but then, this implies $a=1$. Hence, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$.

Your conjecture is proved, therefore is no more a conjecture.

Comment: not $a_{n}<\sqrt[e]{e}$?

Comment: @inequality you are getting confused it is not $(a_n)^\frac{1}{a_n}$. If this were the sequence, then it would be bounded above by $\sqrt[e]{e}$, and therefore would have a convergent subsequence. But in this case, it is clear that $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: sorry,I have edit

Comment: Oh good lord, your edit was $58$ seconds ago. Would  you like me to answer that as well?

Comment: so I have +1 ,and I like it

Comment: @inequality Ok I will try to answer it.

Comment: Having put myself through your conjecture, I now embark upon opening bottles of sambar and rasam (my substitutes for champagne).